# "Generate" client to use Django restful API

Tags: python, django

I have programmed a Django application that provides a RESTful API via [Django Restful Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). That works great. Now I need to create a "client" that uses the API. This client will also be written in Python but run on a different machine than the app.

As the application I already have contains most of the required information how the API can be consumed (i.e. the Django model), it seems possible to "generate" the client code automatically to a large extent. Similar to how the Django Restful Framework "generates" the API code from the model. This would save me from having to use the (awesome, I admit) `Request` module and write a lot of code myself.

I assume I could use the Django Restful Framework's `Serializers`, etc. to have a head start, but that would mean that the client must have Django installed. *That is something that will not be possible*.

What is the best/easiest/preferred/pythonic way to write a (slim) client to consume a Django RESTful API?

---

**EDIT:** I have found "[Slumber](https://github.com/samgiles/slumber)" which seems worth an investigation. There is also [dREST](https://github.com/datafolklabs/drest), but that seems a bit abandoned (last update January 2014).

Comment: Did you run python manage.py makemigrations and migrate yet?  Once you build that you can see the way that those objects interact.

Comment: @sahutchi: I think we misunderstand each other here. I have updated the question to stress that the Django app is working just fine (i.e. yes, I did run `makemigrations` as well as `migrate`). The question is if there is a way to avoid having to write "a lot" of code to write a client that consumes the API.

Comment: Your edit about Slumber is a great answer. Why don't you post it as an answer to your own question?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [Slumber](https://github.com/samgiles/slumber); while it does not leverage/use the Django model at all, it still allows for very quick implementation of a (rather simple) API consumer. Not needing the Django model might even be an advantage in some cases.